# ERROR! Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = AWT-EventQueue-0

Tags: java, exception, timer, listener, illegalstateexception

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I created a timer that updates a Text graphic at the top of my GUI. When the timer runs out though, it changes a variable (which is linked to a listener), and adds a new graphic 'Scene/Group/Node' to my GUI.

-Changing my variable  //Linked to a ChangeListener
-And adding a Scene to my GUI   //Not a listener, but adds new elements to my GUI

Both of these additions cause my program to crash with that error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = AWT-EventQueue-0
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:235)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:393)
```

Sample Error Code:

```
int delay = new Integer(1000); //milliseconds
time_left=time_limit;


ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            timer.setText(time_left+" SECONDS LEFT");


            time_left=time_left-1;
            if (time_left<0)
            {
                //time_left=time_limit;
                mytimer.stop();
                //mytimer.start();
            root.getChildren().get(2).setOpacity(.2);
            //root.getChildren().add(3,newScene());         //This causes to crash      //Adds a new Scene to my GUI
            current_player.setValue(false);         //Also causes to crash - current_player has a Listener on it
                //System.out.println("TIMER RAN OUT!");
            }


        }
};
mytimer=new Timer(delay, taskPerformer);
mytimer.start();
```

my current_player listener:

```
current_player.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
//Code in Here
}
{);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't the exception message obvious. You use a [Swing timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html), which calls its listener on the Event Dispatch Thread (needed when using Swing applications).

However, you update your JavaFX UI on that Thread, instead of on the FX application Thread.

I am not (yet) familiar with JavaFX, but hopefully they have such a timer mechanism as well which you can use, or something similar to `EventQueue.invokeAndWait` which you could use in the `actionPerformed` method

**Edit:**

did a bit of Googling and found [this page about concurrency in JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) which might be a good read. However, no mention of a timer class. Perhaps the [`Animation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html) class is what you are looking for